# Plane versus 3D coordinates

Tags: geometry, plane-geometry, dimensional-analysis, dimension-theory-algebra

We know that line $ax+by+c=0$ is one dimensional and the plane $ax+by+cz+d=0$ is two dimensional.

My question is if line is one dimensional so why 2D points $(x, y)$ are used for line? And if plane two dimensional so why 3D points $(x, y, z)$ are used for plane?

N. B. - I want to understand the intuition rather than details proof.

Comment: The equation you mention for a line is valid for *plane* geometry, which requires only 2 coordinates, whereas the equation for a plane is valid for *solid geometry*, which requires 3 coordinates, that's all.

Comment: A line needs a point $(x, y)$ because it is plotted in plane $0xy$ and the line may have an inclination, so that it is not parallel to $x$ axis neither $y$ axis, and you need 2 coordinates to define it. The same concept is for the plane but in 3D.

Comment: @Alexsp3 I don't understand line is one dimensional means? And plane 2 dimensional means?

Comment: with 2 points you enough information to uniquely describe a line or equivalently you would need a single point and a direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comment of Bernard,  we use two coordinates when we work on a plane (2D) and three coordinates when we work on the space (3D). So the equation $ax+by+d=0$ represents a stright line if it is refferred to points on a plane , but, if it is referred to points in a 3D space, it is a special case of $ax+by+cz=d$, with $c=0$ and it represents a plane parallel to the $z$ axis .

Also, in 3D the (two) equations
$$
\frac{x-x_0}{a}=\frac{y-y_0}{b}=\frac{z-z_0}{c}
$$
represent a straight line.

Comment: why $ax+by+cz+d=0$ is said to be 2D inspite of it has 3 coordinates?

Comment: Because  any point $(x,y,z)$ on it is given if we know  two coordinates. The other one found from the equation.

Comment: your statement "we use two coordinates when  we work on a plane (2D)"-- you mean equation of plane here ax+by+cz+d=0 where z is constant?

Comment: For any  given plane not parallel to the $z$ axis, we can chose a coordinate system such that its equation is $z=0$. In such coordinate system a line on the plane is represented by $ax+by+d=0$